# How to make a javascript widget only show up at certain times

Tags: javascript, time

I'm trying to make a javascript widget only appear on the site between the hours of 6am and 6pm, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, when the webpage is loaded the widget only will be showed if are between 6am and 6pm? Understanding that yes the simple logic is .... [see it working](http://jsfiddle.net/deFreitas/q8eupe4y/1/) and [see the reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

```
var nowIs = new Date();
// if you need to compare the seconds or minutes can use nowIs.getMinutes() and nowIs.getSeconds()
// se more in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
if(nowIs.getHours() >= 6 && nowIs.getHours() <= 18){
    alert("Hey, now is between 6am and 6pm :)");
}else{
    alert("That bad, now is not between 6am and 6pm :(");
}
```